# Tkinkter Grid() alignment not as expected: Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to use grid() function to align the labels and option menu side by side. Here's the code which I used to create a simple GUI:

```py
    from Tkinter import *
    win1 = Tk()
    win1.title("Chumma")

    #Option selection frame:
    f3 = Frame(win1)
    f3.grid(column=0,row=0)
    f3.pack() 
    l1 = Label(f3, text="Select the function which you want to perform: ", bg = "yellow")
    moduleList = StringVar(f3)
    moduleList.set("Normal Walk") #to display the default module name
    o1 = OptionMenu(f3, moduleList, "Normal Walk", "Brisk Walk", "Running", "Custom")
    b3 = Button(f3, text="Execute the option", fg="blue")
    b4 = Button(f3, text="Stop", fg="red")

    #Packing the stuffs in required order:
    l1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W) #E means east
    l1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    l1.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    l1.pack(fill = X, padx = 5)
    o1.grid(row=0,column=1)
    o1.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    o1.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    o1.pack()
    b4.pack()

    win1.mainloop()
```

The result is:

[image: GUI Window:]

I am expecting the option menu `o1` to be at the right of the `l1`.
If I comment the pack command [ `l1.pack()` and `o1.pack()` ], the program is not displaying any GUI at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you call `grid`, a couple of lines later you call `pack` which cancels out the use of grid. Use one or the other but not both for each widget. Sinc `pack` defaults to `side='top'`, your widgets appear stacked on top of each other.

The reason you see nothing if you comment out those *two* calls to `pack` is because you are still calling `b4.pack()`, and you can't use both `pack` and `grid` for different widgets with the same parent.

Also, the calls to `rowconfigure` and `columnconfigure` need to be on the parent widget. Calling them on the label widget will only affect widgets you put inside the label (which is possible, but unusual)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Tkinter does not allow mixing up packing schemes (grid, pack, place) in one frame. Here is example how to organize three widgets.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text='blablabla')
someotherwidget = Entry(root)
button = Button(root, command=lambda: None, text='Boom')

label.grid(row=0, column=0)
someotherwidget.grid(row=0, column=1)
button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Option 'columspan' is like how many columns you want to join to place the widget. We have 2 columns here so if we want to see button not below label but below of both label and someotherwidget we have to specify 'columnspan' option (obviously, analog for rows is 'rowspan')